# Finding initial environment variable values for dynamic variables?

Tags: cmd

The goal is to reset the current cmd.exe shell to have the original set of  environment variables. This should include deleting current environment variables that were created after the cmd.exe shell started.

The System and User environment variables can be read from the registry. But, the dynamic variables such as ALLUSERSPROFILE, APPDATA, LOGONSERVER, etc. are not in those locations. Where can those be found?

Because of this, the code cannot delete a variable created after the cmd.exe shell was started. This is because it may be one of the dynamic variables.

Put both of these files in the same directory.

=== Do-Environment.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\do-environment-script.bat"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0Do-Environment.ps1" >"%TEMPFILE%"
type "%TEMPFILE%"
CALL "%TEMPFILE%"
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

=== Do-Environment.ps1

```
$Vars = @{}

$UserVars = 'HKCU:\Environment'
$SystemVars = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'

(Get-Item -Path $SystemVars).Property |
    ForEach-Object {
        $KeyName = $_
        $KeyValue = (Get-Item -Path $SystemVars).GetValue($KeyName, $null)
        $Vars[$KeyName] = $KeyValue
    }

(Get-Item -Path $UserVars).Property |
    ForEach-Object {
        $KeyName = $_
        $KeyValue = (Get-Item -Path $UserVars).GetValue($KeyName, $null)
        if (($null -eq $Vars[$KeyName]) -or ($KeyName -ne 'Path')) {
            $Vars[$KeyName] = $KeyValue
        } else {
            $Vars[$KeyName] = $Vars[$KeyName] + ';' + $KeyValue
        }
        #'SET "{0}={1}"' -f @($KeyName, $KeyValue)
    }

$Vars.Keys | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object { 'SET "{0}={1}"' -f @($_, $Vars[$_]) }
```

Comment: Most [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) are predefined by Windows itself, especially those depending on user account. They are not persistent stored in Windows registry. Those "shell folders" based environment variables are defined automatically by Windows Explorer instance running as Windows desktop depending on registry keys `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` (REG_EXPAND_SZ) and `Shell Folders` (expanded version of type REG_SZ for downwards compatibility).

Comment: If using PowerShell, try to PInvoke `OpenProcessToken` from "advapi32.dll" and `CreateEnvironmentBlock` from userenv.dll.

Comment: `CreateEnvironmentBlock` pulls data from many sources: current `SystemRoot` and `SystemDrive`; "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"; "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; `GetComputerNameExW`; "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"; `GetTokenInformation`: `TokenUser`; "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<SID>"; "HKU\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"; "HKU\<SID>\Environment"; "HKU\<SID>\Volatile Environment\<Session ID>"; and `GetUserNameExW`.

Comment: Note that values in all "Environment" and "Environment\<Session ID>"  keys are always enumerated in two passes: `REG_SZ` values are loaded first, and then `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values are load. This supports `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values that depend on `REG_SZ` values.